# Moya - unable to call apis with authentication credentials

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, networking, moya

I am developing an iOS app using django rest framework for apis. But currently I am not be able to getting ahead when calling apis with authentication credentials.

I succeeded in calling the api using Postman and curl by setting Header as  `Authentication Bearer <token>`.. but I continuously failed at calling it from iOS app. I am using `Moya` for calling api. And I don't know what I should do next.

What I tried: (when calling Moya)

```
let token = "abcde12345sometoken"
let plugin = AccessTokenPlugin(tokenClosure: token)
let provider = MoyaProvider<AccountAPI>(plugins : [plugin])
provider.request(.getAccountProfile(oauth_id: oauth_id, provider: "facebook")) { (result) in 
    // doing something with result
}
```

and configured API as:

```
extension AccountAPI : TargetType, AccessTokenAuthorizable {

    // codes conforming variables to TargetType protocol

    public var authorizationType: AuthorizationType {
        switch self {
        case .getFacebookAccountToken:
            return .none
        default:
            return .bearer
        }
    }

    public var headers: [String: String]? {
        switch self {
            case .getFacebookAccountToken, .getEmailAccountToken: // post requests
            return ["Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
        default:
            return ["Content-type":"application/json"]
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything I should consider when using Moya for authentication or maybe with Info.plist and so on?
Or the document says this approach is for JWT token, and maybe my method is not for JWT and something else..? Give me some advice!

Comment: What does your header var look like? does it really override what the header is?

Comment: I edited the question adding header var and I think I should add Accept-Language header when it is needed.. any suggestions?

Comment: That is strange. So the header in your API does not override your plugin?

Comment: No I didn't override the plugin.. I think it was the matter of api server that it redirects requests without language code uri, and maybe some errors occur during the process

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I use

- `Moya` `12.0.1`
- `MultiTarget`

example:

```
plugins = [AccessTokenPlugin(tokenClosure: {
    let token = ...
    return token
})]
MoyaProvider<MultiTarget>(
    plugins: plugins
)
.request(MultiTarget(myAPI)) {
    ...
}
```

But it never calls tokenClosure

**Solution**
you need to add this extension

```
extension MultiTarget: AccessTokenAuthorizable {

    public var authorizationType: AuthorizationType {
        guard let target = target as? AccessTokenAuthorizable else { return .none }
        return target.authorizationType
    }

}
```

source: https://github.com/Moya/Moya/blob/master/Sources/Moya/Plugins/AccessTokenPlugin.swift#L62

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of trying this and that.. I found out that it was the api endpoint redirects itself based on the content-language.. so the header that I set is dead when being redirected. So either setting the i18n url in advance or setting the content-language header would solve my problem.